# Remove middle set of brackets inside numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray that looks like this:

```
[[['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.7602,-122.4703']
['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.7941,-122.4078']
['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.8156,-122.284']
['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.8163,-122.2467']
['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.7599,-122.4148']
['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.8268,-122.2526']]

[['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.7602,-122.4703']
['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.7941,-122.4078']
['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.8156,-122.284']
['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.8163,-122.2467']
['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.7599,-122.4148']
['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.8268,-122.2526']]]
```

Is there an efficient way to remove the middle set of brackets so that it looks like this instead:

```
[['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.7602,-122.4703']
['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.7941,-122.4078']
['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.8156,-122.284']
['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.8163,-122.2467']
['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.7599,-122.4148']
['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.8268,-122.2526']
['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.7602,-122.4703']
['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.7941,-122.4078']
['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.8156,-122.284']
['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.8163,-122.2467']
['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.7599,-122.4148']
['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.8268,-122.2526']]
```

I imagine it can be done with looping, but I'm curious if there's a non-loop way to do this, since I want my implementation to scale easily.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like `x[0]` should do it?

Comment: `arr.reshape(-1, arr.shape[2])`. [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) does what you want.

Comment: @ivan - not quite. The shape of the example is `(2,6,2)`, but it's hard to see, because of the missing commas.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Indeed you're right

Comment: Brackets aren't there just for show.  They convey information about the array shape, which by counting blocks, rows and columns appears to be (2,6,2).  Because of how arrays are stored, it is easy and efficient to reshape to ones like (12,2) or (2,12)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to formalize what Michael correctly said:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array(
[[['37.7602,-122.4703', '37.7602,-122.4703'],
['37.7602,-122.4703', '37.7941,-122.4078'],
['37.7602,-122.4703', '37.8156,-122.284'],
['37.7602,-122.4703', '37.8163,-122.2467'],
['37.7602,-122.4703', '37.7599,-122.4148'],
['37.7602,-122.4703', '37.8268,-122.2526']],

[['37.7941,-122.4078', '37.7602,-122.4703'],
['37.7941,-122.4078', '37.7941,-122.4078'],
['37.7941,-122.4078', '37.8156,-122.284'],
['37.7941,-122.4078', '37.8163,-122.2467'],
['37.7941,-122.4078', '37.7599,-122.4148'],
['37.7941,-122.4078', '37.8268,-122.2526']]])

print(array)
array = array.reshape(-1,array.shape[2])
print(array)
```

Output:

```
[[['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.7602,-122.4703']
  ['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.7941,-122.4078']
  ['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.8156,-122.284']
  ['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.8163,-122.2467']
  ['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.7599,-122.4148']
  ['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.8268,-122.2526']]

 [['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.7602,-122.4703']
  ['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.7941,-122.4078']
  ['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.8156,-122.284']
  ['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.8163,-122.2467']
  ['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.7599,-122.4148']
  ['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.8268,-122.2526']]]
[['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.7602,-122.4703']
 ['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.7941,-122.4078']
 ['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.8156,-122.284']
 ['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.8163,-122.2467']
 ['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.7599,-122.4148']
 ['37.7602,-122.4703' '37.8268,-122.2526']
 ['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.7602,-122.4703']
 ['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.7941,-122.4078']
 ['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.8156,-122.284']
 ['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.8163,-122.2467']
 ['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.7599,-122.4148']
 ['37.7941,-122.4078' '37.8268,-122.2526']]
```